# How do I remove duplicate files in directory?

Tags: shell-script

I have a directory with lots of xml files like the file name pattern below:

```
12345_65786.xml
12678_78907.xml
12345_89076.xml
```

Now I need to remove 12345_65786.xml or 12345_89076.xml. How can I do that?

I need to remove the duplicate files based on the similar value present before the "_" in the filename.

Comment: How to know which one?

Comment: @heemayl Anyone of them must be deleted. '12345' which is before '_' is similar. based on that i need to remove the duplicate files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
ls | awk -F_ 'p[$1]++ { printf "rm %s\n",$0;}' | bash
```

where

- `-F_` use `_` as separator
- `p[$1]++` count and test prefix
- `{ ... }` print `rm filename` if above count greater than 1
- `| bash` do actual remove (skip this part for a preview)